# Truth.assertAbout and JavaSourceSubjectFactory.javaSource()

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing, google-truth

I'm writing an annotation processor and want to write some unit tests for it by using `google-compile-testing` and `truth`:

So I want to write a very simple unit test.

```
import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertAbout;
import static com.google.testing.compile.JavaSourceSubjectFactory.javaSource;

@Test
  public void componentOnConcreteClass() {
    JavaFileObject componentFile = JavaFileObjects.forSourceLines("test.NotAClass",
        "package test;",
        "",
        "import my.annotation.MyAnnotation;",
        "",
        "@MyAnnotation",
        "interface NotAComponent {}");
    assertAbout(javaSource()).that(componentFile)
        .processedWith(new MyProcessor())
        .failsToCompile()
        .withErrorContaining("interface");
  }
```

So basically I have copy an pasted a simple test from google's dagger2 repo and replaced the relevant data with my annotation processor.
I'm using maven, and I'm using the same dependencies as dagger2:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.testing.compile</groupId>
            <artifactId>compile-testing</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
            <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But I can't compile the code. I guess there is an generics param problem, but can't figure out what the problem is.

```
Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ProcessorTest.java:[46,5] method assertAbout in class com.google.common.truth.Truth cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: com.google.common.truth.SubjectFactory<S,T>
[ERROR] found: com.google.testing.compile.JavaSourceSubjectFactory
[ERROR] reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) S,T exist so that argument type com.google.testing.compile.JavaSourceSubjectFactory conforms to formal parameter type com.google.common.truth.SubjectFactory<S,T>
```

Any hint what I'm doing wrong? I can't find any difference to google dagger2 tests (which by the way compiles on my machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact `com.google.testing.compile:compile-testing:0.5` [depends on `org.truth0:truth:0.15`](https://github.com/google/compile-testing/blob/compile-testing-0.5/pom.xml) which is the [old location](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/truth0/truth/0.23/truth-0.23.pom) of Truth.  Try using version `0.6` of `compile-testing` instead.